Why am I getting a "duplicate source root" error in IntelliJ when the folder is not marked as a source root?
I'm getting the following error in IntelliJ:
Source root '/path/to/project/src/main/resources' is duplicated in module 'myModule'.

However, when I check the "Project Structure" under the Sources tab, the src/main/resources folder is not even marked as a source root. I’ve tried removing and re-adding the folder, but I still keep seeing this duplication error:
Has anyone encountered this issue before, or know how to resolve it?
Thanks in advance for your help!

A typical situation where you end up in getting the warning above comes when you started with a Java project that was transformed to a Kotlin project.
While adding Kotlin support to an existing Java project, IntelliJ configures the kotlin-maven-plugin to find the additional sources
<configuration>
  <sourceDirs>
    <source>target/generated-sources/annotations</source>
    <source>src/main/kotlin</source>
  </sourceDirs>
</configuration>

Later you may use the standard way to configure the source roots:
<build>
  <sourceDirectory>src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
  <testSourceDirectory>src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
  ...
</build>

In removing the additional setting (configuration/sourceDirs) from the kotlin-maven-plugin you get rid of the duplicated source root warning.
